# La versión de Gradle de mi proyecto es incompatible con la versión de Java que Flutter está usando para Gradle

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, control-de-versiones

Primero quiero decir que yo quería hacer que se ejecutara un programa de flutter en mi celular que estaba conectado por USB a mi PC, pero me aparecía lo siguiente en la consola:

Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using
for Gradle.

To fix this issue, consult the migration guide at docs.flutter.dev/go/android-java-gradle-error.

Por lo que busque se refiere a que las versiones que utiliza de java o gradle son incompatibles.

----------------------------SOLUCION----------------------------

Me termino funcionando el cambio de versión de gradle, ya que tengo la versión 20 de java  y la compatible con la misma es gradle 8.1 a 8.3 por lo dicho en la siguiente pagina de compatibilidad [-pagina-](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)

también hay un pagina con descripción e indicaciones en cada versión de las compatibilidades de gradle con java [-pagina-](https://gradle.org/releases/)

Teniendo eso en cuenta, deben saber que versión de java tienen para compararlas en las paginas anteriores y corroborar que versión de gradle les funcionara, en mi caso yo tengo la versión de java 20 y tenia gradle 7.5 cosa que no me funcionaba y no me dejaba ejecutar el programa por lo que cambie a la versión 8.2 de gradle y ya funciono con normalidad.

para cambiar de versión en el programa de flutter se debe ingresar a las siguiente secciones:

[imagen de explorador de visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNhaH.png)
en esa sección del explorador abren la carpeta llamada android

imagendentor de la carpeta android se debe abrir gradle y por ultimo el archivo gradle-wrapper.properties en donde se encuentra el link de la versión de gradle:

[![imagen de version 7.5 de gradle][1]][1]

La ultima línea es el link que se debe cambiar, de 7.5 la cambie a 8.2 (versión de gradle compatible con mi versión de java), quedando así:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-all.zip

espero le pueda servir a alguien

Comment: El formato de [es.so] es de _preguntas_ y _respuestas_. En lugar de escribir "solución" en tu pregunta, ponlo en la zona de respuestas, y luego [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tal respuesta.